# How can i get first array key's value which is same in second array value?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have two arrays as follows,

```
$cflags = array("AD" => " " ,"AE" => " " ,"AF" => " " ,"AG" => " " ,"AI" => " " ,"AL" => " " ,"AM" => " " ,"AN" => " " ,"AO" => " " ,"AQ" => " " ,"AR" => " " ,"AS" => " " ,"AT" => " " ,"AU" => " " ,"AW" => " " ,"AX" => " " ,"AZ" => " " ,"BA" => " " ,"BB" => " " ,"BD" => " " ,"BE" => " " ,"BF" => " " ,"BG" => " " ,"BH" => " " ,"BI" => " " ,"BJ" => " " ,"BM" => " " ,"BN" => " " ,"BO" => " " ,"BR" => " " ,"BS" => " " ,"BT" => " " ,"BV" => " " ,"BW" => " " ,"BY" => " " ,"BZ" => " " ,"CA" => " " ,"CC" => " " ,"CD" => " " ,"CF" => " " ,"CG" => " " ,"CH" => " " ,"CI" => " " ,"CK" => " " ,"CL" => " " ,"CM" => " " ,"CN" => " " ,"CO" => " " ,"CR" => " " ,"CS" => " " ,"CU" => " " ,"CV" => " " ,"CX" => " " ,"CY" => " " ,"CZ" => " " ,"DE" => " " ,"DJ" => " " ,"DK" => " " ,"DM" => " " ,"DO" => " " ,"DZ" => " " ,"EC" => " " ,"EE" => " " ,"EG" => " " ,"EH" => " " ,"ER" => " " ,"ES" => " " ,"ET" => " " ,"FI" => " " ,"FJ" => " " ,"FK" => " " ,"FM" => " " ,"FO" => " " ,"FR" => " " ,"FX" => " " ,"GA" => " " ,"GB" => " " ,"GD" => " " ,"GE" => " " ,"GF" => " " ,"GH" => " " ,"GI" => " " ,"GL" => " " ,"GM" => " " ,"GN" => " " ,"GP" => " " ,"GQ" => " " ,"GR" => " " ,"GS" => " " ,"GT" => " " ,"GU" => " " ,"GW" => " " ,"GY" => " " ,"HK" => " " ,"HM" => " " ,"HN" => " " ,"HR" => " " ,"HT" => " " ,"HU" => " " ,"ID" => " " ,"IE" => " " ,"IL" => " " ,"IN" => "http://wordpress.dev.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/1317166197_India.png" ,"IO" => " " ,"IQ" => " " ,"IR" => " " ,"IS" => " " ,"IT" => "http://wordpress.dev.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/1317166167_Italy.png" ,"JM" => " " ,"JO" => " " ,"JP" => " " ,"KE" => " " ,"KG" => " " ,"KH" => " " ,"KI" => " " ,"KM" => " " ,"KN" => " " ,"KP" => " " ,"KR" => " " ,"KW" => " " ,"KY" => " " ,"KZ" => " " ,"LA" => " " ,"LB" => " " ,"LC" => " " ,"LI" => " " ,"LK" => " " ,"LR" => " " ,"LS" => " " ,"LT" => " " ,"LU" => " " ,"LV" => " " ,"LY" => " " ,"MA" => " " ,"MC" => " " ,"MD" => " " ,"MG" => " " ,"MH" => " " ,"MK" => " " ,"ML" => " " ,"MM" => " " ,"MN" => " " ,"MO" => " " ,"MP" => " " ,"MQ" => " " ,"MR" => " " ,"MS" => " " ,"MT" => " " ,"MU" => " " ,"MV" => " " ,"MW" => " " ,"MX" => " " ,"MY" => " " ,"MZ" => " " ,"NA" => " " ,"NC" => " " ,"NE" => " " ,"NF" => " " ,"NG" => " " ,"NI" => " " ,"NL" => " " ,"NO" => " " ,"NP" => " " ,"NR" => " " ,"NU" => " " ,"NZ" => " " ,"OM" => " " ,"PA" => " " ,"PE" => " " ,"PF" => " " ,"PG" => " " ,"PH" => " " ,"PK" => " " ,"PL" => " " ,"PM" => " " ,"PN" => " " ,"PR" => " " ,"PS" => " " ,"PT" => " " ,"PW" => " " ,"PY" => " " ,"QA" => " " ,"RE" => " " ,"RO" => " " ,"RU" => "http://wordpress.dev.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/1317166161_Russian-Federation.png" ,"RW" => " " ,"SA" => " " ,"SB" => " " ,"SC" => " " ,"SD" => " " ,"SE" => " " ,"SG" => " " ,"SH" => " " ,"SI" => " " ,"SJ" => " " ,"SK" => " " ,"SL" => " " ,"SM" => " " ,"SN" => " " ,"SO" => " " ,"SR" => " " ,"ST" => " " ,"SU" => " " ,"SV" => " " ,"SY" => " " ,"SZ" => " " ,"TC" => " " ,"TD" => " " ,"TF" => " " ,"TG" => " " ,"TH" => " " ,"TJ" => " " ,"TK" => " " ,"TL" => " " ,"TM" => " " ,"TN" => " " ,"TO" => " " ,"TP" => " " ,"TR" => " " ,"TT" => " " ,"TV" => " " ,"TW" => " " ,"TZ" => " " ,"UA" => " " ,"UG" => " " ,"UK" => "http://wordpress.dev.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/1317166118_United-KingdomGreat-Britain.png" ,"UM" => " " ,"US" => "http://wordpress.dev.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/1317166109_United-States-of-AmericaUSA.png" ,"UY" => " " ,"UZ" => " " ,"VA" => " " ,"VC" => " " ,"VE" => " " ,"VG" => " " ,"VI" => " " ,"VN" => " " ,"VU" => " " ,"WF" => " " ,"WS" => " " ,"YE" => " " ,"YT" => " " ,"YU" => " " ,"ZA" => " " ,"ZM" => " " ,"ZR" => " " ,"ZW" => " ");




$ccode = array("countrycode" => "IN","companyname" => "Appsfrontier","time" => "20 Mins Ago");
```

in second array i have the countrycode as "IN".using this value how can i retrieve the value from first array "IN" => "http://wordpress.dev.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/1317166197_India.png" ?.

Thanks
Ravichandran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this

```
$value =  $cflags[$ccode['countrycode']];
```

its like the directly

```
$value =  $cflags['IN'];
```